# Grab text area content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text area which contains html and text and I want to grab both of them from the text area I did this but it seems that this code get only html codes not the text

HTML CODE

```
<textarea id='post'>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-vAC51myUYpY/VOmdnTh52_I/AAAAAAAAAS4/VUJvhS-NQp4/s1600/Coffee-Splash-1.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-vAC51myUYpY/VOmdnTh52_I/AAAAAAAAAS4/VUJvhS-NQp4/s1600/Coffee-Splash-1.jpg" /></a></div>
<br />
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-gQw0LKXeB9Y/VOmdnWz-uiI/AAAAAAAAAS0/hDyMEZdLXic/s1600/Coffee-Splash-2.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-gQw0LKXeB9Y/VOmdnWz-uiI/AAAAAAAAAS0/hDyMEZdLXic/s1600/Coffee-Splash-2.jpg" /></a></div>
<br />
Ormai sono più di 3 mesi che ho iniziato a fotografare in studio. (Per studio intendo "stanza" dove mi cemento in esperimenti fotografici :P)<br />
Il concetto principalemente rimane lo stesso, ma riuscire a controllare le luci, riflessi e gradienti è diventata quasi la mia sfida quotidiana!<br />
<br />
Ci tengo a precisare che la mia passione rimane sempre la fotografia paesaggistica, purtroppo però ho il vizio di non accontentarmi ma mai e ricerco sempre location che purtroppo non sono alla portata del viaggiatore del "week-end"<br />
<br />
In studio mi cimento spesso nell' action freezing, ovvero nel congelare un movimento, che sia di liquidi o polveri.<br />
<br />
In questo caso ho usato del colorante marrone per cibo, ne ho fatto una pentola intera! La cosa essenziale è il movimento con cui realizzi lo splash...ogni movimento forma uno "shape" diverso. Spesso cambio anche contenitore...<br />
<br />
Le parti in porcellana le ho fotografate tutte singolarmente in modo da poter controllare luce, colore e gradiente.<br />
<br />
La sfida più grande è stata riuscire a fotografare il cucchiaino in acciaio. Notoriamente il metallo è riflettente e se aggiungiamo la parte concava del cucchiaio, beh, riflessi a gogo!<br />
Per ottenere un immagine prima di riflessi, in commercio ci sono dei Light Box, ovvero delle scatole formate da pareti semi trasparenti che permettono di collocare 4 o più luci estremamente, ottenendo oggetti illuminati perfettamente e senza riflessi esterni.<br />
...purtroppo io ancora non ce l'ho...ed ho dovuto affidarmi al mio grande amico photoshop... e meno male che esiste! :D<br />
<br />
Una volta ottenuto tutte le parti, ed aver selezionato la splash migliore, ho unito il tutto sempre su PS.<br />
<br />
Spero che questo post sia di ispirazione!<br />
<br />
Pat.<br />
<br />

</textarea>
```

JQUERY CODE

```
$(function(){
    var pcontent = $('#post').val(),
        content = $($('#post').val());

    console.log(content.html());
});
```

This is a live preview on Jsfiddle for the output http://jsfiddle.net/64x1wrfx/1/

Comment: I think the demo is working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab both the content directly using `.val()` in JQuery.

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    var pcontent = $('textarea#post').val();
    console.log(pcontent);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `console.log($('#post').text());`

Updated fiddle. Textarea content shown in console: http://jsfiddle.net/64x1wrfx/2/

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
console.log($('#post')[0].innerHTML);
```